# Meteor autoform does not wait for element to exist in DOM

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

I'm adding a rendered template to the document via:

```
Blaze.renderWithData(Template.page, Session.get(toAdd[i]), document.getElementById('pages'))
```

This works great... except sometimes with autoform. I'm unsure what's triggering it to happen but some of my autoforms (that can exist inside `Template.page`, they're added to that template dynamically via the data passed in) show, while other throw a client error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formValues' of undefined :: autoform-inputs.js:162 
markChanged :: autoform-inputs.js:169 
updateTrackedFieldValue :: afFieldInput.js:72
```

There's a `timeout` set to 0 in that afFieldInput.js on line 71. Upping this to 500 fixes the error above but is hacky and causes other issues.

The best I can surmise, autoform is attempting to get the form from the DOM by id before it exists in the DOM, probably it exists as a document fragment via Blaze, if I had to guess.

I can confirm that `AutoForm.templateInstanceForForm` is getting the correct form ID, but that `document.getElementById(formId)` is returning null.

The other possibility is that Blaze is, for some reason, failing to render the template but not warning me.

Answer (score 0):

I was WAY off.

I had changed the schema, but was trying to open a doc with improper data for the new schema. Going to post this answer in case someone comes across the same error.

Also, don't pass in objects or functions all the way to the template that autoform doesn't expect, apparently. You can access them still, but remove them from the `attr` object by declaring `attr` as a function in the helper, returning `this.attr` sans any objects that don't need to be sent on to the template.